# Extracting several regex matches in PySpark

Tags: python, regex, string, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm currently working on a regex that I want to run over a PySpark Dataframe's column.

This regex is built to capture only one group, but could return **several** matches.
The problem I encounter is that it seems PySpark native regex's functions (regexp_extract and regexp_replace) only allow for groups manipulation (through the $ operand).

Is there a way to natively (PySpark function, no python's *re.findall*-based udf) fetch the list of substring matched by my regex (and I am not talking of the groups contained in the **first** match) ?

I wish to do something like that:

```
my_regex = '(\w+)'
# Fetch and manipulate the resulting matches, not just the capturing group
df = df.withColumn(df.col_name, regexp_replace('col_name', my_regex, '$1[0] - $2[0]'))
```

With $1 representing the first match as an array, and so on...

You can try the following regex input to see an example of the matches I wish to fetch.

```
2 AVENUE DES LAPINOUS
```

It should return 4 different matches, each with 1 group within.

Comment: only one match in [regex](https://regex101.com/r/2cbuXy/1).. maybe you need [this](https://regex101.com/r/2cbuXy/2)

Comment: I'm updating the regex, I'll make it easier to grasp later.

Comment: there is only one capturing group.. why are you using `$2`.. also what do you expect the end result?

Comment: I said "I wish to do something like that", meaning I'm interested in fetching the matches, not only the capturing groups. So far all we can do with PySpark native functions is to fetch the captured groups (with $1 $2....) of the FIRST match.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to get all the matches.. you can specify matched index using `func.regexp_extract('col', my_regex, idx=1)`..

You will need to write a UDF for this..

Comment: [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21985) is an issue already raised..

Comment: Alright, that's a pitty, but thanks for bringing that up to light. I hope that they won't last too much to release it, feels like a must have when playing with regexs. UDF it is then...

Comment: Feel free to post this as a completed answer below, I'll mark this as resolved. Since there is no other way now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get all the matches in spark. You can specify matched index using **idx**

```
func.regexp_extract('col', my_regex, idx=1)
```

There is an unmerged request for same which can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21985)

**TL;DR**: As of now, you will need to write a UDF for this

Answer (score 10):

In **Spark 3.1+** it's possible using [`regexp_extract_all`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract_all)

> **`regexp_extract_all(str, regexp[, idx])`** - Extract all strings in the `str` that match the `regexp` expression and corresponding to the regex group index.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2 AVENUE DES LAPINOUS',)], ['col'])
df.show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------+
#|col                  |
#+---------------------+
#|2 AVENUE DES LAPINOUS|
#+---------------------+

df = df.withColumn('output', F.expr(r"regexp_extract_all(col, '(\\w+)', 1)"))

df.show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------+--------------------------+
#|col                  |output                    |
#+---------------------+--------------------------+
#|2 AVENUE DES LAPINOUS|[2, AVENUE, DES, LAPINOUS]|
#+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: According to [SPARK-34214](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34214) and [PR 31306](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/31306), this won't be available in PySpark until release 3.2.

Comment: I can swear I tested it on 3.1.

Comment: Ah! Your method will work since it uses `expr`, just not the `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract_all` function.

Comment: This is available in pyspark starting with 3.5.0 according to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract_all.html.